# Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I attempt to use query I get the following error:

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

**Query:**

```
insert into [D:\BACKUP1\ADBASE\APP_DATA\SCIENCECOM.MDF].dbo.Surfaces
(Height, Width, Space, Id)
select 
'0' as Name,
'0' as Width,
'0' as Space,
[D:\BACKUP1\ADBASE\APP_DATA\SCIENCECOM.MDF].dbo.Sides.Id
from [D:\BACKUP1\ADBASE\APP_DATA\SCIENCECOM.MDF].dbo.Sides
```

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Presumably, `id` in one table is declared as `uniqueidentifier`, in the other as an `int`.  The error message is quite clear.  I also doubt that the `name`, `width`, and `space` columns are strings.

Comment: Post the DDL of the dbo.Surfaces and dbo.Sodes tables and the reason for the error should be obvious.

Answer (score -1):

If your Id column is declared as a `uniqueidentifier`, it is probably automatically generated and, therefore, not able to be manually inserted via a query... if I'm understanding your question correctly.